# Which method is better? Hashing each line in a file with PHP

Tags: php, file-io, md5

This question was asked on a message board, and I want to get a definitive answer and intelligent debate about which method is more semantically correct and less resource intensive.

Say I have a file with each line in that file containing a string. I want to generate an MD5 hash for each line and write it to the same file, overwriting the previous data. My first thought was to do this:

```
$file = 'strings.txt';

$lines = file($file);
$handle = fopen($file, 'w+');

foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    fwrite($handle, md5(trim($line))."\n");
}

fclose($handle);
```

Another user pointed out that file_get_contents() and file_put_contents() were better than using fwrite() in a loop. Their solution:

```
$thefile = 'strings.txt';
$newfile = 'newstrings.txt';

$current = file_get_contents($thefile);

$explodedcurrent = explode('\n', $thefile);

$temp = '';
foreach ($explodedcurrent as $string)
      $temp .= md5(trim($string)) . '\n';

$newfile = file_put_contents($newfile, $temp);
```

My argument is that since the main goal of this is to get the file **into an array**, and file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file **into a string**, file() is more appropriate and allows us to cut out another unnecessary function, explode().

Furthermore, by directly manipulating the file using fopen(), fwrite(), and fclose() (which is the exact same as one call to file_put_contents()) there is no need to have extraneous variables in which to store the converted strings; you're writing them directly to the file.

My method is the exact same as the alternative - the same number of opens/closes on the file - except mine is shorter and more semantically correct.

What do you have to say, and which one would you choose?

---

This should be more efficient and less resource-intensive as the previous two methods:

```
$file = 'passwords.txt';

$passwords = file($file);
$converted = fopen($file, 'w+');

while (count($passwords) > 0)
{
    static $i = 0;
    fwrite($converted, md5(trim($passwords[$i])));
    unset($passwords[$i]);
    $i++;
}

fclose($converted);

echo 'Done.';
```

Comment: "intelligent debate", my foot. on the topic "from which end to break an egg"

Comment: Just do whatever makes the most sense to you

Comment: Either way, both methods are slurping the file into memory AND THEN DUPLICATING IT IN MEMORY. You need at bare minimum 2x the file's size for memory to handle this duplication. No biggie for a 2 or 3 line file (with short lines). Major problem if you're looking at a multi-gig webserver access log.

Comment: @MarcB I didn't even think of that. I updated the first post with a new solution that I think requires progressively less memory as it processes the file (depending on the length of each line relative to the size of an MD5 hash).

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments suggests do what makes more sense to you. Since you might come back to this code in few months and you need to spend least amount of time trying to understand it.

However, if speed is your concern then I would create two test cases (you pretty much already got them) and use `timestamp` (create variable with `timestamp` at the beginning of the script, then at the end of the script subtract it from `timestamp` at the end of the script to work out the difference - how long it took to run the script.) Prepare few files I would go for about 3, two extremes and one normal file. To see which version runs faster.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

I would think that differences would be marginal, but it also depends on your file sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose to write a new [temporary file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php), while you process the input one. Once done, overwrite the input file with the temporary one.

Comment: Interesting. After mucking around a bit I decided to instead simply unset()each array element after I wrote the converted value to the file. I think that's less resource-intensive. See updated first post.

Comment: Sure, that's possible. But don't forget that you still allocate memory  as much as the source file [plus some internal data structure information]. The comment from @MarcB still applies.

Comment: True, but am I right in thinking that memory use progressively declines? I guess the other method would be to read each line manually instead of reading everything all at once.

Comment: Do you know exactly how fwrite() operates? Is it bad to be calling that in the loop versus storing everything in an array/temp file?